# How can I get my foreach loop to output the result as one combined array instead of separate ones?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm receiving a JSON input, and I need to run it through a script and get the values returned in a new JSON array. However when I do so, it yields eg 3 separate arrays, not one big one as it received. Example:

```
Input:
[{
        "auth": "aa03e76d0a8bab11e08250000c29b481",
        "topic": "edafdff398fb22847a2f98a15ca3186e/1",
        "value": "1000"
},
{
        "auth": "aa03e76d0a8bab11e08250000c29b481",
        "topic": "edafdff398fb22847a2f98a15ca3186e/1",
        "value": "2000"
},
{
        "auth": "aa03e76d0a8bab11e08250000c29b481",
        "topic": "edafdff398fb22847a2f98a15ca3186e/2",
        "value": "3000"
}]
```

I run it through the following script:

```
function clean($string) {
   $string = str_replace(' ', '-', $string); // Replaces all spaces with     hyphens.
   return preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $string); // Removes special     chars.
}

//Get inputs from request
$data = array();
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$reply_array = array();

//Start looping through data
foreach($data as $mid => $input) {

    //Dig out the installation id and register
    $identify = explode('/',trim($input['topic'],'/'));
    $installation = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9_]+/i','',array_shift($identify));
    $RegisterID = array_shift($identify)+0;

    // Extract the cleaning supplies needed to clean and validate the data
    $sql_get_detergent="SELECT ProfileID, Description, Lvl4, Register, BitNo, DataFormat, Units, LowAct, HighAct, Multiplier, FaultCondition, FaultText FROM DeviceProfiles WHERE RegisterID = '".$RegisterID."' ORDER BY RegisterID ASC";
    $result_get_detergent = mysqli_query($con,$sql_get_detergent);
    while($row_clean = mysqli_fetch_array($result_get_detergent)) {

        //Write out the reply
        $semantic = strtolower($row_clean['Lvl4']);
        $reply_array['topic'] = $installation."/".clean($semantic);
    }
    print_r(json_encode($reply_array));
}
```

Output is not what I need - as seen here it yields 3 separate arrays, not one big one.

```
Current output:
{"topic":"edafdff398fb22847a2f98a15ca3186e\/"}
{"topic":"edafdff398fb22847a2f98a15ca3186e\/"}
{"topic":"edafdff398fb22847a2f98a15ca3186e\/"}

Desired output:
[{
  "topic":"edafdff398fb22847a2f98a15ca3186e\/"
 },
 {
  "topic":"edafdff398fb22847a2f98a15ca3186e\/"
 },
 {
  "topic":"edafdff398fb22847a2f98a15ca3186e\/"
}]
```

What am I doing wrong? Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are printing each result in the `foreach` loop, and in the next iteration of the loop you overwrite the previous result.
Of course you get three single results that way.

Change your code like this:

```
$all_replies = array();
foreach($data as $mid => $input) {
    // [...]
    while($row_clean = mysqli_fetch_array($result_get_detergent)) {
        $reply_array = array();
        // Do you logic here - you can fill $reply_array as you want.
        $all_replies[] = $reply_array;
    }
}
print_r(json_encode($all_replies));
```

You could also use this approach, which is a smaller change:

```
$reply_array = array();
foreach($data as $mid => $input) {
    // [...]
    while($row_clean = mysqli_fetch_array($result_get_detergent)) {
        // [...]
        $reply_array[]['topic'] = $installation . "/" . clean($semantic);
    }
}
print_r(json_encode($reply_array));
```

That will work for your example case, but you'll not be able to set another value apart from `topic` in a new assignment. You'd have to do it this way:

```
$reply_array = array();
foreach($data as $mid => $input) {
    // [...]
    while($row_clean = mysqli_fetch_array($result_get_detergent)) {
        // [...]
        $reply_array[] = array(
            'topic' => $installation . "/" . clean($semantic),
            'auth'  => $your_auth_value,
        );
    }
}
print_r(json_encode($reply_array));
```

I prefer the first solution with an extra variable, but the other one works, too.

Answer (score 0):

There is a small mistake in your code.

Replace below code :

```
$reply_array['topic'] = $installation."/".clean($semantic);
```

with :

```
$reply_array[]['topic'] = $installation."/".clean($semantic);
```